# Firestore - how to structure users friend's posts

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm looking for the efficient way to model users friend's posts

so @Frank van Puffelen, @Doug Stevenson, @Alex Mamo ... all other champions, a simular question is posted **3 years ago** [Firebase Firestore, query a users friend's posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49163379/firebase-firestore-query-a-users-friends-posts)

so I need to make sure that we are up to date for this topic on 2021 :)

data structured :

```
Firestore-root
   |
   --- users (collection)
   |     |
   |     --- uid (documents)
   |          |
   |          --- name: "name"
   |          |
   |          --- email: "email"
   |
   --- friends (collection)
   |      |
   |      --- uid (document)
   |           |
   |           --- friends (collection)
   |                 |
   |                 --- uid (documents)
   |                 |
   |                 --- uid (documents)
   |
   --- posts (collection)
   |     |
   |     --- postId (documents)
   |          |
   |          --- uid: "user id"
   |          |
   |          --- postId: "postid"
   |          |
   |          --- userName: "userName"
   |          |
   |          --- message: "message"
   |          |
   |          --- lastModified: "yyyymmdd hhmm"
   |          |
   |          --- likeCount: "xxx"
   |          |
   |          --- commentCount: "yyy"
   |          |
   |           --- likes (collection)
   |          |      |
   |          |      --- uid (documents)
   |          |      |
   |          |      --- uid (documents)
   |          |
   |          |
   |           --- comments (collection)
   |                 |
   |                 --- commentId (documents)
   |                 |
   |                 --- commentId (documents)
   |
   --- feeds (collection)
   |     |
   |     --- uid (documents)
   |          |
   |           --- posts (collection)
   |                 |
   |                 --- postId (documents)
   |                          |
   |                          --- uid: "user id"
   |                          |
   |                          --- postId: "postid"
   |                          |
   |                          --- userName: "userName"
   |                          |
   |                          --- message: "message"
   |                          |
   |                          --- lastModified: "yyyymmdd hhmm"
   |                          |
   |                          --- likeCount: "xxx"
   |                          |
   |                          --- commentCount: "yyy"
```

**NOTE** : I'm using this feeds structure because Firestore does not allow query with array lists more then 10 element (the user's friends).

workflow :

- user adds a post -> post added to posts collection

  - When this happens it triggers a Firebase Function :

    - get uid from post ( field uid in post doc )
    - find friends ids from friends/uid/friends ( probably have friends list as array in user doc is better to avoid reading multiple docs in friends collection ) --> this will return list of friends ids
    - loop on friends ids and copy the post to each friends feeds/friendUserId/feeds/postId
- user like a post -> uid added to the posts/postId/likes/uid

  - When this happens it triggers a Firebase Function :

    - increment likeCount field in posts/postId doc
    - increment likeCount field in feeds/{anyId}/posts/postId  ( use collectionGroup )
- user comment a post -> uid added to the posts/postId/comments/uid

  - When this happens it triggers a Firebase Function :

    - increment commentCount field in posts/postId doc
    - increment commentCount field in feeds/{anyId}/posts/postId  ( use collectionGroup )

query :

- get current user and friends posts order by most recent
  FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('feeds').doc(currentUserId).collection('posts').orderBy('lastModified', descending: true)
- get top N liked posts

  FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('posts').orderBy('likeCount', descending: true)

**NOTE** : purge Firebase Function can be trigger to delete all posts > X months

**Question** : Should I go with this structure ? if No any suggestion will be appreciated :)

Comment: "Should I go with this structure ?" Why shouldn't you? What's single specific concern is keeping you from using this structure?

Comment: Thanks @FrankvanPuffelen for your quick answer !!!  

Why shouldn't you ? I have already starting using this structure, just needed expert confirmation

What's single specific concern is keeping you from using this structure ? nothing for now except duplicate data, but with firebase function purge 
mechanism that I will put in place I think it should be fine.

Comment: This is really way to vague to be directly answerable - is there something not working? also, the descriptions don't match the ascii art (nice art job btw). For example, when a user adds a post, the text says 'get uid' but there's no uid stored in the post so you can't track it back to the poster. Also, it says *copy the post to all friends feeds/friendUserId/feeds/postId*. Why copy the entire post? Why not just just add the postId to an 'my_unread_posts' document instead of all of the data? There's a number of inconsistencies that make it challenging to evaluate without deep discussion.

Comment: you are right @jay, I have update based on your comment, answer below, is there something not working ? I cannot answer this now because I'm starting implementation based on this design, and this is why I have share this design to have expert feedback and to make sure that there is no big issue with this design,  descriptions don't match -> update based on your comment

Comment: Why copy the entire post? I have a view ( Home view like Facebook home view ) contain user post + all friends posts order by last posts, a post is a card contain body, message, like count ..., this card is updated on mealtime based on Listener, so I'm not able to find another solution except copy all the post infos to all friends and implement a Listener for collection feeds/uid/feeds, if there is any other alternative this will resolve lot of problem for me

Comment: to make it simple the goal is to have a view contain list of cards ( a card is a post contain body, message, picture of current user or friend )
so current user and friends can like and comment post ( card ) on realtime, if friend like or comment post I can see it in realtime in this view. Thanks all for your understanding !